# Cast List<int> to List<string> in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Can you cast a `List<int>` to `List<string>` somehow?

I know I could loop through and .ToString() the thing, but a cast would be awesome.

I'm in C# 2.0 (so no [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)).

Answer (score 157, accepted):

.NET 2.0 has the `ConvertAll` method where you can pass in a converter function:

```
List<int>    l1 = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } );
List<string> l2 = l1.ConvertAll<string>(delegate(int i) { return i.ToString(); });
```

Answer (score 125):

Updated for 2010

```
List<int> l1 = new List<int>(new int[] { 1,2,3 } );
List<string> l2 = l1.ConvertAll<string>(x => x.ToString());
```

Comment: No, lambdas were introduced in C# 3.0 so this will not work in 2.0.

Comment: I found that it works with VS2008 and .NET 2.0, as long as you have at least .NET 3.0 installed.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341846/use-certain-lambda-expressions-when-targeting-net-2-0

Comment: People should differentiate between .NET version and C# version. Since the arrow `x => x.ToString()` is compiled to the same kind of IL as is `delegate(int x) { return x.ToString(); }` in this case the important thing is to have a C# compiler (C# version) that knows what `=>` is. The framework and runtime (.NET version) needs no special features for this, so .NET 2.0 is fine here.

Comment: Turns out you can ditch `<string>` and it still works.  Making it just `l1.ConvertAll(x => x.ToString());`

Answer (score 8):

Is C# 2.0 able to do `List<T>.Convert`? If so, I think your best guess would be to use that with a delegate:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Convert(delegate (int i) { return i.ToString(); });
```

Something along those lines.

---

Glenn's answer is probably the correct code ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
List<int> items = new List<int>(new int[] { 1,2,3 } );
List<string> s = (from i in items select i.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

You wouldn't be able to directly cast it as no explicit or implicit cast exists from int to string, it would *have* to be a method involving .ToString() such as:-

```
foreach (int i in intList) stringList.Add(i.ToString());
```

**Edit** - or as others have pointed out rather brilliantly, use intList.ConvertAll(delegate(int i) { return i.ToString(); });, however clearly you still have to use .ToString() and it's a conversion rather than a cast.

Comment: The existence of a cast between the generic types has nothing to do with the ability to cast between the projection. IE, even if `int` were implicitly or explicitly convertible to `string`, that doesn't mean that `List<int>` has an implicit or explicit conversion to `List<string>`.

Answer (score 3):

`result = listOfInt.Select(i => i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList()`

replace the parameters result and listOfInt to your parameters

Comment: For  me worked correctly                                                                                           
result = listOfInt.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

Converting from int List to string List can be done in two adittional ways besides the usual ToString(). Choose the one that pleases you more.

```
var stringlist = intlist.Select(x=>""+x).ToList();
```

Or also:

```
var stringlist = intlist.Select(x=>$"{x}").ToList();
```

And finally the traditional:

```
var stringlist = intlist.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to build a new list.  The underlying bit representations of `List<int>` and `List<string>` are completely incompatible -- on a 64-bit platform, for instance, the individual members aren't even the same size.

It is theoretically possible to treat a `List<string>` as a `List<object>` -- this gets you into the exciting worlds of covariance and contravariance, and is not currently supported by C# or VB.NET.

Comment: [@Curt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942/cast-listint-to-liststring#44950): > It is theoretically possible to treat
> a List<string> as a List<object> --
> this gets you into the exciting worlds
> of covariance and contravariance, and
> is not currently supported by C# or
> VB.NET C# and .NET does actually support Covariance. Just not with generics.