# Use (certain) lambda expressions when targeting .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

ReSharper suggests we change:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
};
```

Into:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

It looks a bit cleaner. But we are targeting .NET 2.0. Is this still something we should do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should choose which of them you prefer the most. In C# 3.0 all features introduced (such as Lambda expression, extension methods and LINQ) are build on the 2.0 .NET runtime. So you can develop using C#3.0 and run it on the 2.0 of the runtime.

As long as your *compiler* can handle C#3.0 you can use all the new C#3.0 features. The only exception I know of is that if you use Expression trees you'd need to use .NET 2.0 SP1 because some of the bug fixes in the CLR for that service pack is needed to make expression trees work properly.

Answer (score 8):

You can use it as long as you use VS2008 (or later) for development. Lambda expressions is a feature of C# language, it's **not** a feature of .Net Framework.

Comment: Do you mean the .NET 3.5 C# compiler is the necessary piece? (which can build code targeting .net 2.0 only)

Comment: @JimmyHofa: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Technically, the C# 3.0 compiler is the necessary piece. There is no such thing as the ".NET 3.5 C# compiler" (but most people can probably guess what you mean)