# c# compile in old framework

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I made an app in C# framework .NET 4.0 for Windows 7 x64. I have now been asked to install this app on Windows XP x86 that has only framework 3.0 and some apparently might have only 2.0. Updating to framework 4.0 is not an interesting option since there are 400+ terminals.
My question is: can my app be compiled in any framework version(like 2.0) and work on any terminal ? if not any suggestions on how I can make this work ?

Comment: You have to try yourself. If you use some feature available only in framework 4.0 then no, you need to search the error and rewrite the code for the minimum expected framework available

Comment: Go to your project properties and select ".NET Framework 2.0" as target platform. Remove references, that are not available any longer. Try if it compiles - it will probably fail, if you've used things like Lambdas, LINQ, TPL, ...

Comment: If you using Visual studio [How to: Change the Target .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: By the way, if the terminals are in an AD domain deploying the .NET Framework 4.0 is just a matter of setting a group policy; 10 minutes of work on the server and at the next reboot they'll be all installing the framework automatically.

Comment: How are you "installing" your app? If it is an installer, just include the .Net 4.0 with it.

Comment: @Aschratt Not necessarily - lambdas are a compiler feature, not a framework feature, so they should work even in code compiled for 2.0. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341846/use-certain-lambda-expressions-when-targeting-net-2-0

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: Good to know :) Still my comment applies to other runtime features.

Comment: @Aschratt Indeed. TPL and LINQ are out of scope. Writing for .NET 2.0 without LINQ seems like such a pain today...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> can my app be compiled in any framework version(like 2.0)

Sure, just go to Project->Properties in Visual studio and set the Target Framework.
[image]

Be aware, however, that some features that you've built into your app may not be available in older frameworks.

Comment: thanks... I was also wondering if it is compiled in 2.0, will it work a Windows 7 ?

Comment: Yes, Windows 7 included .NET 3.5, which includes .NET 2.0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use 2.0 features you can compile to it. Just set (in the project properties) the target framework to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the target framework of your application. There is [article about this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on MSDN.

However, if you used some features from .NET 4.0 you'll have to update yuour code to not use them anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any .NET 3 or higher classes or DLLs then sure you can target your projects to .NET 2.  What I would do is open each project's settings and target it to .NET 2.  Then recompile.  If this all works then all is well and you can deploy to the target machines.

You'll have to change the Target Framework setting for each project in Project->Properties.