# Is it safe to use newer C# features when building for older .NET Framework versions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I maintain a .NET 2.0 library (currently, using Visual Studio 2013).

I have used a code-inspection tool on the code of the library and was surprised when the tool suggested using `??` operator or lambdas instead of some of the code.

I was even more surprised when I applied suggested edits and the library was successfully built after that.

Why the library with `Target Framework` set to `.NET Framework 2.0` can be built with newer features of C# in it's code?

Is it safe to use newer C# features when building for older .NET Framework versions? I mean, the users of the library can have .NET Framework 2.0 only and I want them to be able to use the library even if I use lambdas in it's code.

Comment: Re Lambdas: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341846/use-certain-lambda-expressions-when-targeting-net-2-0). Just make sure everyone else in the team is using VS >= 2010

Comment: `??` is a C#2 feature. Lambdas are a compiler feature so you can use them when targeting .Net 2, but the delegate types defined in .Net 3.5 (`Action`, `Func` etc.) will not be available.

Comment: Pretty unproductive to get stuck on a 9 year old version of a free library.  Your tool vendor certainly didn't have that problem :)

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, I would be happy to move from 2.0 to 4.0 (at least) but the library is used by people with older versions of development tools and I can leave them behind. Maybe it's another version of Chicken and Egg problem, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.NET 2.0 and C# 2.0 are 2 different things. In your case you could perfectly fine have a .NET 2.0 library (which is targeting the CLR 2.0) and use the C# 3.0 compiler which supports for example lambda expressions.

So you should make a difference between your compiler version and the version of the CLR you are targeting. Since you are using VS 2013, you could use newer versions of the compiler.

> Is it safe to use newer C# features when building for older .NET Framework versions?

Yes, perfectly safe. The generated assembly is still targeting the CLR 2.0 and will run without any issues with this older version of the CLR.

Comment: And I'll add to this that you can even use LINQ while targeting .NET 2.0 by using [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Basically, new C# language features can be implemented in the compiler without requiring extensions to the underlying .net framework. It isn't always done like that, but it may be.

In the case of lambdas, they were introduced in C# 3.0. So you need a compiler of that level or above. However, the new features introduced in C# 3.0 were all built using the features of .net 2.0. So you can use lambdas under .net 2.0.

In essence, the new functionality here is implemented in the compiler rather than the framework.

As for the null-coalescing operator, `??`, it was introduced in C# 2.0 so there's nothing surprising about being able to use it under .net 2.0.

Comment: Just a small remark, but the question did not mention nullable types (`?` "operator"), just the coalesce (`??`) operator - which was introduced in .NET 2.0, as well.