# Transferring c# List to another list with a method inbetween

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

Was'nt sure of the title, but I have this task which I am having trouble with.

I have a List downloaded from a WCF service.

ie:

```
 List<Stops_edited_small> StopsList = new List<Stops_edited_small>(e.Result);
```

The list has several items

two being:

```
LatitudeField
LongitudeField
```

Basically, what I need to do is make a Geocoordinate value for each record in the list by doing this:

```
GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(LatitudeField), Convert.ToDouble(LongitudeField));
```

Then add the Geocoordinate value in each record in a new List which I can then use.

Make sense?
I am not sure on how I would go about this.
Would i need some kind of foreach loop to do the Geocoordinate conversion on my original list someone? Would i have to convert it into a class first to do this?

Thanks, any help or thinking welcome.

(EDIT: just to add this is on windows phone, so .net 4 is available)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or later you can use LINQ2Objects

```
var coordinateList = StopsList.Select(stop =>
    new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(stop.LatitudeField),
                      Convert.ToDouble(stop.LongitudeField))).ToList();
```

If you are using an older .NET version you need to use an explicit loop.

```
var coordinateList = new List<GeoCoordinate>();
foreach(var stop in StopsList)
{
    coordinateList.Add(
        new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(stop.LatitudeField),
                          Convert.ToDouble(stop.LongitudeField)));
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to combine both the new `GeoCoordinate` with the stops you have a couple of options.

Either create a list with an anonymous type

```
var combinedList = StopsList.Select(stop =>
    new {
        s = stop,
        coord = new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(stop.LatitudeField),
                      Convert.ToDouble(stop.LongitudeField)),
    }).ToList();
```

You can also do the same with a class you create, replace `new {` with `new YourClass {`.

You can also use the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method using both above lists

```
var combinedList = StopsList.Zip(coordinateList, Tuple.Create).ToList();
```

This gives you a `List<Tuple<Stop, GeoCoordinate>>`.

Note that most of the time you can skip `.ToList()`, you don't get a `List<T>`, but an `IEnumerable<T>`. That will work as good as a `List` in most cases but your program don't have to copy everything to lists all the time. Usually a little bit more efficient and you don't need to type `.ToList()` all the time.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I think I am halfway there, as I probably need to create a new list and combine the values from the old list to the values from this new list. so basically my old list also has this geocoordinate values in it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I used the first suggestion with the new YourClass bit :-) works a treat!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the ConvertAll method that goes back to .NET 2.0 before Linq has been introduced.

Here is an example:

[Cast List<int> to List<string> in .NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942/cast-listint-to-liststring)

And MSDN Article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx